# CFHTTP running longer than Timeout specified

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm using ColdFusion 5 and specifying a timeout=2 on the CFHTTP tag.  But I've seen the CFHTTP take much longer, sometimes as much as 8 seconds.  I thought the timeout parameter was the max time the CFHTTP would execute.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the throwonerror="yes" parameter as well, to make it fail and throw an error message.

I'm not sure if CF5 has that though, it has been a while since I used that version. :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be that your app has some performance issues, maybe reviewing the code, for better performance, might be of more help.